# What is the best solution to get and compare hours + minutes from LocalDateTime with given hour?

Tags: java, date, datetime, localdatetime

I am implementing a service (not going to production anywhere anytime) which should receive a `LocalDateTime` and a `Duration` and should check if given time is between company working hours (which are 8:00-22:00), the working hours should be (somehow) configurable:

lets say that I have a:

```
public class CompanyWorkingHoursService {
    private static final Int OPENING_HOUR = 8;
    private static final Int CLOSING_HOUR = 22;

    private boolean isMeetingBetweenWorkingHours(LocalDateTime beginningDateTime, Duration duration) {
        LocalDateTime endingDateTime = beginningDateTime.plus(duration);
    }
```

and I'm stuck.

I can change the type of `OPENING_HOUR` and `CLOSING_HOUR` to whatever I want. I can get hours and minutes from `LocalDateTime` but those are integers. And I don't want to compare whole dates - i need just hours and minutes.

I have found some solutions using `java.util.Date` but I would like to stay with `LocalDateTime` if possible...

Comment: have you checked which methods `LocalDateTime` offers?

Answer (score 3):

The "best" thing is to avoid integers. So define the opening and closing hours as `LocalTime`, and compare the dates using the `isAfter()`, `isBefore()` and `equals()` provided by `LocalTime`:

```
private static final LocalTime OPENING_HOUR = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
private static final LocalTime CLOSING_HOUR = LocalTime.of(22, 0);

private boolean isMeetingBetweenWorkingHours(LocalDateTime beginningDateTime, Duration duration) {
    LocalDateTime endingDateTime = beginningDateTime.plus(duration);
    return !beginningDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(OPENING_HOUR)
            && !endingDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(CLOSING_HOUR));
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `isAfter` and `equals`, you could also use `!isBefore`, which is much better readable, IMO.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes that would be indeed better!

Answer (score 0):

If *the working hours should be (somehow) configurable*, you could pass them to the method, too. Afterwards create `LocalDateTime` instances from those values in combination with the date of the meeting.

Maybe like this:

```java
public static boolean isMeetingBetweenWorkingHours(
                LocalDateTime startMeeting, Duration meetingDuration,
                int openFrom, int openUntil) { // pass start and end hour of day
    /* 
     * create the working time hours using the hours of day passed 
     * and using the date of the meeting start passed
     */
    LocalDateTime startWorkingHours = LocalDateTime.of(startMeeting.toLocalDate(),
                                                        LocalTime.of(openFrom, 0));
    LocalDateTime endWorkingHours = LocalDateTime.of(startMeeting.toLocalDate(),
                                                        LocalTime.of(openUntil, 0));
    // calculate the end time of the meeting
    LocalDateTime endMeeting = startMeeting.plus(meetingDuration);
    // then return if the meeting fully fits into the working time slot
    return !startMeeting.isBefore(startWorkingHours)
            && !endMeeting.isAfter(endWorkingHours);
}
```